# Set a referenced variable to a newly initialized class

Tags: php, oop, promise, guzzle

I have a method, which takes a reference

```
// CarService.php
public function getCars(&$carCollection = null)
{
    $promise = // guzzle request for getting all cars would be here
    $promise->then(function (ResponseInterface $response) use (&$carCollection) {
        $cars= json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
        $carCollection= new CarCollection($cars);
    });
}
```

However, when accessing the collection and trying to reuse it, I'm getting the error

`Argument 1 passed to {placeholder} must be an instance of {placeholder}, null given`

I know that the reason for this is, that the constructor returns nothing, but how can I still assign my variable to a new instance of the `CarCollection` (which extends Doctrine's `ArrayCollection`)

I even tried it with a static method as a work around

```
// CarCollection.php
public static function create(array $cars): CarCollection
{
    $carCollection = new CarCollection($cars);
    return $carCollection;
}

// CarService.php
public function getCars(&$carCollection = null)
{
    $cars = // curl request for getting all cars would be here
    $carCollection = CarCollection::create($cars)
}
```

but it's still null. Why is that? How can I set a referenced variable to a new class?

I access the method like this

```
$carService = $this->get('tzfrs.vehicle.services.car');
$carCollection = null;
$promises = [
    $carService->getCars($carCollection)
];

\GuzzleHttp\Promise\unwrap($promises);

var_dump($carCollection); // null
```

When I set the reference directly, eg.

```
// CarService.php
public function getCars(&$carCollection = null)
{
    $carCollection = new CarCollection([]);
}
```

it works without any problems. Seems like the callback is somehow the problem.

Whoever downvoted this, can you please elaborate why and why you voted to close?

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling the `getCars` method.

Comment: Sure, I have added some code

Comment: Sorry @PeeHaa, I removed it. Thought it would be for developing under PHP 7, not for PHP 7

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but you should be able to modify an object when passing by reference. See here for an example: https://3v4l.org/KtFvZ

In the later example code that you added, you shouldn't pass `$carCollection` by reference, the `&` should only be in the method/function defintion, not provided when you call it. I don't think that is your problem though, that should be throwing an error in php7.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I didn't have the `&` in the method call. Was a writing error. But it still doesn't work. When I do a `echo get_class` it returns the `Controller` where I call the `CarService` so it looks like it has somehow set himself

Comment: Ok, I somehow tracked the error down. When I set the variable directly in the method it works without problems, but in my case I have another callback function and when I set `$carCollection` in there, it doesn't work. I'll update my code